# I can not get the parameters from notification intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm trying to pass a parameter by notice

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message,int groupid,int count) {

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("group_id",groupid);
        Log.d("mylogout","group_id: "+groupid);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification   = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
               .................
                .build();
        notification.number=count;
        notificationManager.notify(groupid, notification);
    }
```

and take it in my Activity

```
Log.d("mylogout","id from: "+getIntent().getStringExtra("group_id"));
```

but for some reason the first log writes id = 3 but in MyActivity log writed `D/mylogout﹕ id feom main: null`

Comment: groupid is int or string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("group_id", 0);
```

You are having `groupid` as an 'integer' in method parameters.

`private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, String message,int groupid,int count)`

But trying to get it as a string in  your activity will return null.

Comment: my mistake. thank you. I thought that the string ID, and forgot that changed the type.